# rowModelType = 'infinite' with latest ag-grid version,when I reset the rowHeight and reset datasource,the rows loading exception

Tags: ag-grid

Our requirement is that the table whose rowModelType is 'infinite' needs to change the height dynamically, but when I reset the row height and reset the data source, the row data cannot be displayed, and the data cannot be loaded by scrolling.[image]

```
//set rowHeight and datasource
    this.setState({rowHeight:20})
    setTimeout(()=>{this.gridApi.setDatasource(this.state.datasource)},0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that only serveSide mode can set the row height, and only the initialization takes effect.